# Implementing (secure) Api Keys in an app

Tags: php, security, web-applications, sniffing, api-key

I wrote a Web Application and I would like to allow other developers to get the information from it.

The server Im working on is not that awsome and cant handle that many request, so the idea is to generate and assign api keys to everyone that wants to query our information. With Api keys I can limit the daily requests and perhaps collect some statistics to see what information is really useful for the other developers.

The thing is, Im concerned about the security aspect of it. Since the Api key is going to be sent to our server (via GET/POST etc), someone could sniff the request with wireshark and get the developers API key without much effort, right?

I thought about generating a secret key and an API key. I could then instruct the other developers to concatenate them and send a hash of it to our API. I would then validate that the hash is valid and allow the request... But then the same problem would persist. A hacker could still sniff that hash and make requests on behalf of the other developer's app.

So my questions are

- How can I avoid this problem?
- Or better yet, Is my concern even valid? Is that a real problem?
- Is there a better and secure way to allow access to my information without making it too complicated for the other developers?

What do you guys think?

Comment: I have down voted this by accident (I can't even remember having read this). How can I undo this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to solve a bunch of different questions here.

If your objective is to limit the number of requests to your server, you should create a throttling mechanism. This is non-trivial, but I'd base it on IP address rather than a license key - a single licensed user might swamp your system with lots of requests. You can throttle by IP address without implementing a license mechanism.

If you want to create a licensing scheme, you need to understand cryptography etc. - it's a non-trivial problem. For instance, how do you stop a legitimate user sharing their license key with all their friends? How do you stop a hacker from stealing your key and sharing it with all of his friends?

There are a number of solutions to this - they all impose some degree of pain on your users. For instance, you can run your service on HTTPS; this stops snooping, but reduces performance. You can issue "tokens" for your service which expire after a certain number of uses; getting new tokens requires a cryptographic exchange (which might check your IP address). You might require a "challenge/response" type of logic (including an IP address validation). All these steps make life harder for your users; they probably won't thank you much for the extra work they have to do.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to sniff, your problem can be solved with HTTPS on your server.

Answer (score 1):

it definitely makes sense to put some authentication on the API if you want to limit access + potential some usage rate limits. If you use an API key and want to avoid sniffing then HTTPS is definitely the way to go. If that's not an option then you can also use a hash-style auth like oAuth 1.0 (http://oauth.net/core/1.0/) or Amazon AWS authentication. These work by issuing your API users with an ID and a Secret. They use the secret on the client side by inserting it into the message body, computing a hash and including the hash (not the secret) in the request. On the incoming side you compare the hash with the same operation done on the message content with their specific secret included.

This means that you can verify the sender without having to send the secret over the wire (note that the content still isn't secure - but you avoid passing the key over the wire with every request). The downside is that it's complex for developers to implement. Even if you use the oAuth 1.0 pattern which there are libraries for it's a bit of an overhead.

I work at 3scale and some of our tools might be helpful also - our systems provide API Keys, oAuth Secret sharing and also API rate limits out of the box (http://www.3scale.net and the PHP libraries are here: https://github.com/3scale/3scale_ws_api_for_php).